# PDFsharp: Reading "/A" from an Outline

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Given a specific PDF document that I have, using PDFsharp, I want to go over its bookmarks/outlines. For some of these outlines, an /A is defined. I want to get /A's content. However, I was unable to find it.

For example, one of the outlines is defined as follows:

```
7142 0 obj
<</Title <FEFF00430031>
/Count -2
/First 7143 0 R
/Last 7144 0 R
/Parent 7141 0 R
/Next 7145 0 R
/A 928 0 R
>>
endobj
```

I want to get the `/A 928 0 R` line.

Given a PdfOutline that represents this object, I can
(1) get its object id using Internals.ObjectId.
(2) get title, first, last, parent, next using the Elements dictionary.

I can't, however, manage to get the /A part. I would appreciate help with that!

(I do know that I can get 928's defined /GoTo action using Element["/Dest"]. However, I am not interested in that. Ultimately, I'm interested in the "928" value. (Since object 929 is actually what I'm after, which I currently find using document.Internals.GetObject(), but this is probably unrelated.))

If I try using

```
docSharp.Internals.GetObject(C1.Internals.ObjectID)
```

I get the same thing. Instead of showing a `/A 928 0 R` line, I get 928's contents `/Dest [ 10 0 R /FitR 376 799 1115 354 ]`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found [this PDFsharp forum post](https://viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3663&hilit=%2FA%20action) (after [posting there as well](https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4468&p=13846#p13846)).

Using the `outline.Elements.GetDictionary("/First");` way of accessing the outlines got me what I wanted. Given a PdfDictionary d that represent my corresponding outline, I can get the "/A" value using `d.Elements.GetString("/A");` .

Traversal through the PDF objects is done using the "/First", and "/Next" keys on d.Elements.GetString.